# PyGame Multitouch Support (Windows 8)

Tags: python, windows, touch, pygame, multi-touch

Is there any way of getting Windows 8 multitouch events to work with PyGame? Is there any way at all of accessing touch events from within Python in Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pygame does not directly support multitouch, and essentially queues up multitouch interactions as separate mouse events. However, you can bypass the pygame mouse event system and utilize the [touchpy](https://code.google.com/p/touchpy/) library to process/handle touch & multitouch input. A series of tutorials for handling this exact problem can be seen [here](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/). For convenience, here are the links to tutorial [one](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/getting-started-with-multi-touch-development-in-python/), [two](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/getting-started-with-multi-touch-development-in-python-part-2/), [three](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/getting-started-with-multi-touch-development-in-python-part-3/), and [four](http://xelapondsstuff.wordpress.com/2008/12/03/getting-started-with-multi-touch-development-in-python-part-4/). Tutorials three and four might be of particular interest to you as it shows examples of integrating pygame with touchpy.